# Append comma to character array in java

Tags: java

I have a character array. I want to add comma(,) after each 3rd character. I tried the following code.

```
    public class Comma {
    char [] str = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
    char [] buf = new char[15];
    int size = str.length;
    int c=1;
    public void insert()
    {
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            {
                  c++;
                  if(c%3==0)
                  {
                    buf[c] = ',';
                    i++;
                  }
                  buf[i]=str[i];
             }  
            System.out.println("Final String");
            for(int i=0;i<buf.length;i++)
            System.out.print(buf[i]);
   }
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
        Comma c = new Comma();
        c.insert();
   }

   }
```

I am getting the following output:

```
Final String
1 345 789
```

Can someone correct me?

Comment: Boss!!!! Character is always '1' character long!!.. u cannot append anything to it. try string array

And now the solution, change   if(c%3==0) to   if(i%3==0)

Comment: 123,456,789 is it your required output???

Comment: (i%3)==0 not works because i start with 0 and at first time it gives true and append , and we only want asfter 3rd char. So I posted tested ans after run on my machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

output :

```
Final String
123,456,789
```

here is the code

```
public class Comma {
    char[] str = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
    char[] buf = new char[20];
    int size = str.length;
    int c = 1;
```

`public void insert() {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (c % 4 == 0) {
            buf[c - 1] = ',';
            i--;
        } else {
            buf[c - 1] = str[i];
        }
        c++;
    }
    System.out.println("Final String");
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(buf[i]);
    }
}

public static void main(final String args[]) {
    Comma c = new Comma();
    c.insert();
}`

}

Answer (score 0):

This one will generate `123,456,789`.

```
public class MySimpleClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        char [] str = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i=1; i<=str.length; i++) {
            output.append(str[i-1]);
            if (i%3==0 && i<str.length) {
                output.append(",");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(output);
    }

}
```

If you want to generate formmatted number read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html.

Comment: Have you dry run run your program it append , just after printing 1st character

Answer (score 0):

```
        int j = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
              c++;
              if(c%3==0)
              {
                buf[j] = ',';
                j++;
              }
              buf[j]=str[i];
              j++;
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
 int c=0;
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
  {
       if((i+1)%3==0)
       {
         buf[c] = ',';
         c++;
       }
     buf[c]=str[i];
    c++;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to add the comma from the left: you want "23,304", not "233,04".

```
List<Character> chars = new LinkedList<Character>(Arrays.asList('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'));
int positionForNewComma = chars.size() - 3;
while (positionForNewComma > 0) {
chars.add(positionForNewComma, ',');
    positionForNewComma -= 3;
}
System.out.println(chars);
```

If you add the comma from the right, it is instead:

```
List<Character> chars = new LinkedList<Character>(Arrays.asList('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'));
int positionForNewComma = 3;
while (chars.size() > positionForNewComma) {
    chars.add(positionForNewComma, ',');
    positionForNewComma += 3 + 1; // + 1 size the insertion moves the elements on the right
}
System.out.println(chars);
```

It's better to avoid using raw arrays: []. If you do use raw arrays, it looks more Java-ish to declare them as "char[]" instead of "char []".